# Is it possible to pause and resume downloading object from aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to pause the download process of object of aws s3 object. And after a while, I can resume the download process?
My app is developed using electronjs.
Does aws-sdk-js support the two kind of actions? If it does not support, is there any other way I can do this. Thanks.

Comment: In practice pause/resume download operations are implemented using [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) and the AWS S3 `GetObject` operation does support a similar `Range` parameter.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.